# Do I need to have the same name to transfer Gta from 360 to ps4

Tags: xbox-360, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online, psn, xbox-network

So I have Gta on Xbox 360 and I only want to transfer my Gta to Ps4 does that mean I need to make my 360 GamerTag the same as ps4?

Comment: You mean savegames?

Comment: Just my Gta online character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer your character from Xbox 360 to PS4 without having the same gamer tag name.

Once you have made your PS4 account you will need to link your GTA social club account and XBL account. Then when you sign in you should be prompted to start the transfer.

[Here are more detailed instructions on doing so](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-or-Xbox-One)

Comment: Do I need to have Xbox live gold setup for this to work or just my Xbox 360

Comment: Just your XBL account information should be fine. You should not need Xbox Gold to import your character.

Comment: @Jay I just wanted to follow up, did this process work for you?